# How to create list of dictionaries from merging two lists together, where the keys are repeated

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists:

```
lst = [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1]

keys = [[2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 2, 4, 1]]
```

I would like to create a list of dictionaries and output:

```
d = [{2: 1.1, 3: 1.1, 1: 1.1, 4: 1.1}, {2: 1.1, 1: 1.1, 4: 1.1, 3: 1.1}, {3: 1.1, 1: 1.1, 2: 1.1, 4: 1.1}, {3: 1.1, 2: 1.1, 4: 1.1, 1: 1.1}]
```

I have tried `d = [dict(zip(keys, i)) for i in lst]`

but this returns `TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration`

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the keys:

```
l = [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1]
keys = [[2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 2, 4, 1]]
d = [dict(zip(i, l)) for i in keys]
print(d)
```

Output:

```
[{2: 1.1, 3: 1.1, 1: 1.1, 4: 1.1}, {2: 1.1, 1: 1.1, 4: 1.1, 3: 1.1}, {3: 1.1, 1: 1.1, 2: 1.1, 4: 1.1}, {3: 1.1, 2: 1.1, 4: 1.1, 1: 1.1}]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I think I just stared at it for so long I ended up confusing myself.

Answer (score 1):

For each element `d` in `keys`, you want to create a dictionary created by zipping each element of `l` with `d`, so

```
[dict(zip(d, l)) for d in keys]
```

Comment: I'd btw rephrase the "you want to" claim with "you could". It's not clear what they want. They might very well want to use the first `l` value for the first dict, the second for the second, etc. (Hence my clarification question.)

Comment: Thanks for this. It's exactly what I was trying to do. Very kind.